# PHP script stopping right after "$com = new Com('WScript.shell');"

Tags: exec, php-5.3, wsh

I'm trying to debug a huge php script file that when reaches this line

```
$com = new Com('WScript.shell');
```

The whole script just dies and stops working. I'm debugging in using Eclipse PDT.

I tried adding `echo`s before and after that line and ran the file from the command line

```
php -f "C:/path/file.php" argument
```

Where `argument` is just a number, it still doesn't pass this line !

I'm new to php and I can't debug this error any further. Is there a way to test why a script is stopping this way ?

I'm using php 5.3

Thank you

Comment: @sectus, where is that ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the `php_com_dotnet.dll` plugin. The I didn't know where php threw it's errors so I knew that an error log can be configured by adding this line `error_log = "C:\php\php_errors.log"` in php's `php.ini` file.